# Gulp: update version number in Angular website?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'm using [`gulp-bump`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump) to update the version of my Angular app. The version is written to the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "WebProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
      ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      ...
  }
}
```

How can I, inside a gulp task, write this version number to a HTML div inside my *index.html* file? Maybe it should be done in another way.

I would like the version number on my website to be in sync when building it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a template engine. You could basically use anyone for that purpose. But here's an example using [Swig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swig) for a template language and [gulp-consolidate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-consolidate) for your gulp task.

Add this to your HTML

```
<div>{{ version }}</div>
```

And add this to your Gulpfile

```
var consolidate = require('gulp-consolidate');
var data = require('./package.json'); // your data is your package.json

gulp.task('addversion', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe(consolidate('swig', data)) // and pass it to swig
        .pipe(gulp.dest('whereever/you/want/it/to/be'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a plugin just for this: [gulp-inject-version](https://github.com/dvinciinteractive/gulp-inject-version)